# How Make a Batch-file for Selected Word?

Tags: batch-file, hyperlink

I have a text file that include some urls like :

```
http://www.amazon.com/Armed-Struggle-History-Richard
http://www.amazon.com/Irish-Freedom-History-Nationalism-Ireland/
http://www.amazon.com/Armed-Struggle-History-Richard-English
http://www.amazon.com/Ernie-OMalley-Intellectual-Richard
http://www.amazon.de/Ernie-OMalley-Intellectual-Richard
http://www.amazon.uk/Ernie-OMalley-Intellectual-Richard
http://www.amazon.de/Irish-Freedom-History-Nationalism-Ireland/
```

I want When Run Batch-file Select all urls have amazon.com and Make this result:

Put all title after / amazon.com/ in [B][/B] and remove - and replace space
then put urls in [link][/link]

```
[B]
Armed Struggle History Richard
[/B]

[link]
http://www.amazon.com/Armed-Struggle-History-Richard
[/link]

[B]
Irish Freedom History Nationalism Ireland
[/B]

[link]
http://www.amazon.com/Irish-Freedom-History-Nationalism-Ireland
[/link]

[B]
Armed Struggle History Richard English
[/B]

[link]
http://www.amazon.com/Armed-Struggle-History-Richard-English
[/link]

[B]
Ernie OMalley Intellectual Richard
[/B]

[link]
http://www.amazon.com/Ernie-OMalley-Intellectual-Richard
[/link]
```

Comment: And if you are going to do this, I *strongly* suggest using something other than a batch file. Try python, or powershell. Or literally *anything* else.

Comment: How use PowerShell for Selected word ?

Comment: @moh3en check my answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this batch file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Batch Hyperlink Maker
Set "file=urls.txt"
Set "KeyWord=amazon"
Set "OutputFile=OutputFile.txt"
If exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File%" ^| find /I "%KeyWord%"') do (
    @for /f "tokens=3 delims=/" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        Call :Replace %%b
        echo [B]
        echo !Title!
        echo [/B]
        echo(
        echo [link]
        echo %%a
        echo [/link]
        echo(
        (
            echo [B]
            echo !Title!
            echo [/B]
            echo(
            echo [link]
            echo %%a
            echo [/link]
            echo(
        )>>"%OutputFile%"
    )
)
Start "" "%OutputFile%" & pause >nul & exit
::*******************************************************************
:Replace <String>
Set "Title=%1"
Set "String=-"
Set "NewString= "
Rem replace the dash "-" by a space " " into a String
Call Set "Title=%%Title:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Set "String=.html"
Set "NewString="
Rem replace the string ".html" by a "" into a String
Call Set "Title=%%Title:%String%=%NewString%%%"
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
```

Comment: Some of my links in urls.text have link for some text like .html and show in title. how i can remove all html in title with this batch-file ?

Comment: Thank you @ Hackoo , I check last update . When run it no effect for make OutputFile.txt and OutputFile.txt is empety